# Scipy Cosine Similarity is very slow using Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cosine-similarity, collaborative-filtering

Few days back i have started learning Python by doing a project. 
I have two dataframes that i prepared out of my data which are User and Item Dataframes. User DF has the 17k distinct users and Item DF has 1,500 albums. I am using collaborative filtering to get the cosine similarity between two dataframes
as below

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
for i in range(0,len(user_normalized.index)-1):
 for j in range(0,len(item_matrix.index)-1):
  item_matrix_cpy.at[j, 'cosine'] = 1 -cosine(item_matrix_same_shape.iloc[j], user_normalized.iloc[i])
```

I observed that my looping logic is performing very slow and running for ever to complete. I tested the logic for few users (<10), observed that cosine computation is taking longer to execute (~12s). But when i tried to run the same cosine logic for all the users(i.e 17K) , the query is taking forever to complete.
Can you guys help me here ?

Answer (score 4):

Let's do some quick benchmarking of calculating cosine similarity so we have a baseline understanding of its performance

```
timeit.timeit('cosine_similarity(x,y)',setup='from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity; import numpy as np; x,y = np.random.random(100),np.random.random(100)',number=20000)
4.5380048290098784

timeit.timeit('cosine(x,y)',setup='from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine; import numpy as np; x,y = np.random.random(100),np.random.random(100)',number=20000)
0.6468068649992347
```

So it seems that `scipy's` cosine outperforms that of `sklearn`, so we probably won't benefit from switching the implementation... Moving on.

If you want to perform pairwise cosine similarity for a matrix of 17k entries, that equates to roughly `17k^2` evaluations == `289,000,000` which is already a lot, and especially more so if your vectors are high-dimensional as well.

Let's see how fast cosine similarity can be done on a `thousandth` of your input, so `289,000` evaluations.

```
timeit.timeit('cosine(x,y)',setup='from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine; import numpy as np; x,y = np.random.random(100),np.random.random(100)',number=int((17000**2)/1000))
9.857225538988132
```

It takes about 10 seconds. Since this grows linearly with the number of cases... You can expect to spend 10,000 seconds, or a bit less than 3 hours to perform around 300 million cosine similarity operations (in my case on vectors of length 100).

So the cosine similarity calculation just has to take a certain amount of time. One way your code can be potentially improved, is you can store the cosine similarities in a new dataframe, or new series, and then connect it to your original dataframe using an index, as opposed to adding to the dataframe at each iteration of the loop using the `at` method (probably very slow).

If all of this makes sense, then your computational load is high enough such that a lil ol' laptop starts to feel weak. What you do next depends on your use case - does this need to be done once? Just run it and forget it.

Need to do it occasionally but not too often? Parallelize your implementation (if you have four cores, use all of them at once) using python's `multiprocessing` module (important to not use `multithreading`, it won't work in this case).

Need to run this frequently? You might need more hardware, or look into cloud computing solutions - you'd be surprised at how affordable a properly managed cloud computational setup can be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed analysis. Really appreciate your time.  To answer your question on frequency - I need this code to execute once in a while but not all very often. So in my case can there is any approach to make my Cosine computation quick?

Comment: @NedunuriRajesh look into Dask's dataframes, they provide support for parallel processing of dataframes. You can speed up your solution by parallelizing, and by not storing the calculated cosine similarities in the same dataframe, but it in a new dataframe/series (and then connecting them later if need be).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` which takes 2 matrix as input. This method is much more efficient than doing the computation for each pair separately.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity(
    item_matrix_same_shape.values,
    user_normalized.values
)
```

Here is the [sklearn's implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py) line 888:

- It uses only numpy matrix operation, without any python for loop
- It computes the norm only once for each sample (user, album) by `normalize` function. With your code, the norm of each album vector is computed 17K times !